# Apply max function to a specific column in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I created a list whose each element is a dataframe.

```
list <- [df1, df2, ...]
```

columns of each df are

```
col1   col2
```

I want to check within each dataframe, for a particular column (say col1), what is the maximum value

So if I do something like this

```
max(list[EachElement]$col1)
```

Any help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sapply`

```
sapply(lst, function(x) max(x$col1))
```